# prove that $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$ w.r.t these metrics

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Prove that $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$  w.r.t these metrics:

$d_{2}(x,y)=(\sum_{k=1}^{n}(x_{k}-y_{k})^2)^\frac{1}{2}$

$d_{0}(x,y))=\max_{1\leq k\leq n}|x_{k}-y_{k}|$

my attempt of proving

$\mathbb{Q}^n$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^n\Leftrightarrow $   $\mathbb{R}^n$ is contained in closure of $\mathbb{Q}^n$

So take $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and try to prove  $x\in closure\;  of \; \mathbb{Q}^n$

I know the idea but i can't write a rigorous proof

Comment: do these all produce the usual topology? no need to waste labour.

Comment: It is sufficient to show the distance to every subset of R^n is 0. Thus no balls are in the complement of Q^n (and thus its closure). The complement of the closure is open and not a ball: it is the null set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

$(1)$ $d_0$ and $d_2$ give rise to same topology on $\mathbb{R}$. This topology is the usual topology on $ \mathbb{R} $. In the case of $n=2$, a ball of radius $1$ in $d_0$ looks like a disc, and in $d_2$ looks like a square. Intuitively, inside each disc we can find a square and inside each square a disc. Extend similar arguments to the general case.

$(2)$ A dense set has a nonempty intersection with every nonempty open subset of 
the space.

$(3)$ Show that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. This is not so difficult if you use Hint $(2)$.Using this, show that $\mathbb{Q^n}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R^n}$. For a point $x=(x_1,x_2,...x_n) \in \mathbb{R^n}$ construct a sequence that converges to it. This can be done by thinking about constructing a sequence for each individual $x_i$.