# Prove that $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the Euclidean metric.

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

I know that the subset $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$ if cl ($\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{R}^2$. I am not sure how to show this.

Comment: This might help you http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/779958/prove-that-mathbbqn-is-dense-in-mathbbrn-w-r-t-these-metrics?rq=1

Comment: Do you know how to prove that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Yes, I have seen a proof for this, but it doesn't use anything about metric spaces.

Comment: Use this from the link: A dense set has a nonempty intersection with every nonempty open subset of the space. And now take a ball with center in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and then prove that there is a point $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Q}^2$ in it.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, hence for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon>0$ there is some $q(x,\varepsilon)\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that 
$|x-q(x,\varepsilon)|\leq\varepsilon$. Given $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, you may consider that
$$ \left\|(x,y)-\left(q(x,\varepsilon/2),q(y,\varepsilon/2)\right)\right\|\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon $$
by the triangle inequality, hence $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This seems like the most straightforward path to the result.

Answer (score -1):

the complement of the closure is an open set. THe closure contains Q^2. The only possible open set is the null set.