# Is $\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$ closed in $\mathbb{R^2}$?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

I reviewed some of the general topology materials to enhance skills in real analysis. The following problem struck me to the core:

**Problem:** Is there a set that is not bounded, not closed, and not open in $\mathbb{R^2}$

**My answer:** Take $\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$.

I wonder if this is a true example. Are there few other examples? Thanks. WY.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the matter?

Comment: It is a valid example. Examples of such are myriad

Comment: What’s the definition of closed? The answer becomes easily apparent using a specific definition of closed

Comment: Any finite set not open or closed and copied with no overlap an infinite number of times.

Comment: Since it is a topology question you need to specify the topology on R^2

Comment: Your example is fine: since $\Bbb Q$ and its complement are dense in $\Bbb R,$ they are not closed, i.e. $\Bbb Q$ is neither closed nor open, and the same holds for $\Bbb Q^2$ in $\Bbb R^2.$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the Euclidean metric.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1995035/prove-that-mathbbq-times-mathbbq-is-dense-in-mathbbr2-with-the-eu)

Comment: @IrbidMathThere is a nearly universal understanding that if the topology on $\Bbb R^n$ isn't specified, it is the usual one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A closed set is a set with open complement. This is equivalent to saying it contains its limit points (I leave this as an exercise). Consider the sequence $\{(p_n,0):p_n\in\mathbb{Q}\}$. By choosing our $p_n$, we can make it converge to an irrational value, thus, $\mathbb{Q}^2$ does not contain all its limit points, and is not closed.

It is also not open because its complement is not closed (look at sequences of irrational numbers converging to $0$).